# I wanna hide this little white-thing on the JTable

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, jtable, background-color

The picture shows a thin (1 pixel?) white margin (marked in blue) inside the border of a JTable.

How can the margin be eliminated, or the colour be changed?

I have tried:

- Changing the JTable
- Changing the ScrollPane

I set both to opaque without success.

Thanks for help.

[image: Picture]

Comment: I'm gonna be honest... I don't see a white screen.

Comment: what a stupid mistake .. thanks John V.  ;-)

Comment: @John V. Make your answer official (not a comment) so it can be accepted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sides there are simply the border set by whatever JComponent its contained in.  Remove the border (or change it to a line border for instance) and that style will go away.  :)